# Show views only on one specific node

Tags: views

I think my question is very simple, but I was searching for long time for a good solution.

How do you integrate in Drupal 7 one views (e.g. page or block) inside or after one single node (e.g. node/10). What is the best solution?

Until now I used the drupal block system to attach one views-block after a single node. But I read, is not a good solution.

Thanks

Comment: You can also use [panels](https://drupal.org/project/panels) or [context](https://drupal.org/project/context) modules to embed views in a page.

Answer (score 1):

That's the best use case for the [Viewfield module](https://drupal.org/project/viewfield). It works providing a custom field, so you can "attach" a view to nodes.

You can provide a default view if you want to display the same view on many nodes.

Or you can provide a custom argument to pass to the view.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In view block, select filter criteria, select title